# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined (AJAX POST CALL)

Tags: ajax, kendo-grid

The application successfully reaches this function:

```
save: function ()
        {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors",
                type: "POST",
                data: directorData
            }).done(function () {
                alert('done!');
            });
        },
```

directorData contains the following:

```
{
    "awardTitleId": "1",
    "personId": "1657",
    "nameId": "1651",
    "isOnBallot": "True",
    "concatenationString": "test1"
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is what the controller looks like:

```
public void PostDirector(Director director)
    {
      myConnection.Open();
      var query = "INSERT INTO ...";
      var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Successfull call on Ajax, try below code

> $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
>
> $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();